# How to programmatically capture emails? (like posterous)

Tags: php, email, cron

I need to programmatically capture emails as well as any files that are attached to them using php.  Also is running a cron job the only way to continue checking if there are any new emails or is there a way to automatically fire some code as a new email arrives?  Thanks any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the second part of your question: If you run your own mail server and want to avoid polling to fetch new messages, then you can add an entry to /etc/aliases that lets your MTA know to forward to your PHP script, like so:

`uploads: "|/usr/bin/php -q /var/flickr/uploads.php"`

This entry will tell your MTA to pipe any emails for `uploads@example.com` to `uploads.php`. From there, you can read `STDIN`, parse the MIME message, and processes it as you please

(stolen from Cal Henderson's Book [Building Scalable Websites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356). I highly recommend Chapter 6)

Comment: This is great, but my epic fail godaddy web host doesn't let me do this apparently.  Should I switch web hosts (if so to what host)?  Or is there a way to do this with godaddy?

Comment: If your host doesn't allow it, then polling POP or IMAP may be your only choice.

Comment: I'm thinking about just switching to http://bluehost.com.. anyone have any experience with them?.. any other recommendations for a web host that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that does exactly that.

1. Create a daemon (regularly executing program), called InboxDownloader that connects to your inbox and checks for messages. If there are messages, have that daemon just download them and place them into a folder for further processing.
2. Create another daemon MailProcessor, that goes through the downloaded files and parses them out. The way I go about it is using regular-expression based signatures to determine what kind of message arrived. I have a set of classes that each register as a potential "handler" for this type of a message, and if the match is made, the handlers "execute logic" method is executed, and the full contents of the method are passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at how [Postie](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/) does it for WordPress?

See also [the Fetchmail tool](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/).